# windows 7 professional upgrade to windows 10

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-10-upgrade

I was upgrading to windows 10 and it snagged at 99 %.
I shut it down after 8 hours snagged at this number.
  Upon turning it on in the morning it said it was installing something but it went too fast for these old eyes to read.
 Came to the usual screen.
  Admin and guest. I am both.
  Clicked admin.  Black Screen.  After doing control, alt, delete, I clicked change user and then came on as guest........(later edit)
 OK, a few days have passed and it seems as if windows 10 has reverted back to windows 7, with only the firefox server gone.  No problem with downloading that.
**My questions now is:**
 My system has only 2.0 RAM installed.  is this enough ram for windows 10 to install and work adequately? If not, how would I get more ram?  would an external hard drive gain me more ram for the upgrade?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to [edit] your question with the formatting tools to make it easier to read. This will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Answer (score 0):

[This Microsoft webpage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs) will help with the required specifications for your computer. 2Gb of RAM is within the minimum required but I personally would add some more RAM if you can for better performance.

RAM size and hard drive size is different.  They relate to different hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 requires 1 GB of RAM for the 32 bit version and 2 GB for the 64 bit version.  See the requirements [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs).

Hard drives and RAM are completely different things.  Adding another hard drive will not get you more RAM.

In my opinion, if Windows 7 ran acceptably for you with 2 GB, then Windows 10 should as well.  However, depending on your machine, you can upgrade the RAM.  [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) has an easy to use tool to detect your machine type and give you possible RAM upgrades.

Comment: Thank you Keltari.  I have gone to the link you provided and it advised two upgrades to memory (affordable) and something called SSD (not affordable on my budget.  In your opinion how profitable would it be to upgrade just the memory, as opposed to this SSD, starting at aaproximately 200.00.  Elder on budget.

Comment: I wouldn't bother upgrading hardware until you upgraded the OS.  It might work fine for you.  If you feel its slow, memory is the first thing to upgrade.  You dont have to buy from Crucial, but it tells you what type of memory you should get.  I would skip the SSD.